# Предотвратить исполнение скрипта js на ОС Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Как предотвратить исполнение скрипта js на ОС Android.
В настоящее время в моем проекте имеется скрипт (а именно [maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput)), который действует на всех устройствах. На android он работает не корректно.
Пока не нашла решение, хочу отключить его исполнение только для android.

Нашла код определяющий мобильный браузер:

```
var isMobile = {
Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
},
BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
},
iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
},
Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
},
Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
},
 any: function() {
      return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() ||          isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
}
};

if(isMobile.Android()){
 //действие, которое нужно сделать, если браузер Android
   }
```

Но как его применить к моей задаче, т.е. как отключить действие скрипта?

**UPD**

чтобы подключать скрипт для всех устройств кроме android, такой способ подойдет?:

```
                if( !isMobile.Android() )    $.getScript("jquery.maskedinput.min.js",    function(){
   $("#acctNumber").mask("999999");
    $("#sumCheck").mask("99999");
    $("#cardNumber").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999?999", {placeholder: ''});
     $("#cardCode").mask("999", {placeholder: ''});
     });
```

Comment: Вам не _отключать_ по условию, а _подключать_ jQuery плагин по условию нужно.

Comment: мне нужен вариант именно с отключением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделала так:

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};


if(!isMobile.Android()){
    $("#acctNumber").mask("999999");
    $("#sumCheck").mask("99999");
    $("#cardNumber").mask("9999 9999 9999 9999?999", {placeholder: ''});
    $("#cardCode").mask("999", {placeholder: ''});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вариант 1**
Как писал @Dmitriy Simushev, вам нужно наоборот подключать скрипт по условию:

```
if( !isMobile.Android() ) $.getScript("jquery.maskedinput.min.js", function(){
   alert("Script loaded but not necessarily executed.");
});
```

*Погуглите в сторону загрузки скриптов, и выберите, что вам по душе, если не нравится этот подход*

**Вариант 2**
Не совсем тру, но имеет место быть:

```
<script id="maskedinput">
  /// ТУТ КОД jquery.maskedinput.min.js
</script>
if( isMobile.Android() ) $("#maskedinput").remove();
```

Comment: почему не "тру"? в чем м.б. подвох?

Comment: а если как-то так? `if(isMobile.Android()){
 return false;
   }`

Comment: `$("#maskedinput").remove();` это значит что он весь блок удалит?

Comment: Не тру, потому что код самого плагина в коде страницы, хотя это и ускоряет работу, потому что мы сперва интегрируем код, а потом удаляем, а правильнее подключать по условию. `return false` прекратит вообще весь JS код. `$("#maskedinput").remove()` - удалит DOM элемент с идентификатором `maskedinput` и всем его содержимым, а значит всю инфу и методах, предназначенных для маски.

Comment: то есть, чтобы подключить скрипт, надо перечислить все устройства кроме Android? как-то это не правильно...

Comment: Опечатался, естественно - if( !isMobile.Android() ){ LOAD_SCRIPT }

Comment: `if( !isMobile.Android() ){ LOAD_SCRIPT }` не совсем поняла этот код. это значит что скрипт загрузится, но не будет работать на android ?

Comment: Смотрите Вариант 1. Это комментарии!! LOAD_SCRIPT просто для сокращения.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день, на самом деле все просто, после трех дней мучений в поиске ответа, он оказался совсем прост. Не нужно отключать `masketinput` для андроида. Проблема андроида в том, что для mask которые имеют разделители происходит сдвиг курсора.

Решение:

```
//Проверка на ОС андроид, и подмена маски , борьба со сдвигом курсора

(function () {
    if (isMobile.android.device) {
       $(".phonefield")
       .mask("389999999999");
    }
    else {
       $(".phonefield").mask("38(999)999-99-99");
    }
})();
```